# Поиск и вывод из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Не совсем понимаю рабочие моменты. Подскажите как реализовать.
При загрузке главной страницы выводится таблица из БД

```
<body>
<div style="margin-top:35px"></div>
          
</div>  <!------- ПЕРВОЕ ЗАПОЛНЕНИЕ ТАБЛИЦЫ ------>
       <?php
               $sql = pdo()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `details`");
               $sql->execute();
               $result = $sql->fetchAll();
       ?>
<div style="margin-top:10px">
   
   <table class="tablekassa">
       <tr>
         <th>№</th>
         <th>Артикул</th>
         <th>Производитель</th>
         <th>Название</th>
         <th>Кол-во</th>
         <th>Цена</th>
         <th>Партия</th>
         <th>Магазин</th>
         <th style="background:red">Стеллаж №</th>
         <th style="background:red">Полка №</th>
         <th style="background:red">Коробка №</th>
         <th>Состояние</th>
         <th>Комментарий</th>
         <th></th>
       </tr>
           <?php foreach ($result as $value) { ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?=$value['id'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['articul'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['manufacturer'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['detail'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['quantity'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['price'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['partiya'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['stellazh'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['magazine'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['polka'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['korobka'] ?></td>
           <td><?=$value['sostoyanie'] ?>
           <td><?=$value['comment'] ?></td>
           <td>
  </table>
```

Теперь я добавил инпут и кнопку для поиска в базе данных.

```
<form  class="searchinput" method="post" action="do_search.php"> <!--- Вызов поиска в БД-->
            <p><input  type="text" name="search" id="search"> <input type="submit" value="Поиск"></p>
    </form>
```

При нажатии кнопки я перехожу в do_search.php
Там делаю поиск

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/boot.php';
$sql = pdo()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE `articul` = :search");
$sql->execute(['search' => $_POST['search']]);
$result = $sql->fetchAll();
?>
```

Как мне теперь передать данные и снова на главной странице вывести уже ту строку или те строки которые нашел? Или как вставить код поиска из do_search.php на главной странице чтобы он сработал только по нажатию кнопки. Там ведь уже отображается таблица. Как ее обновить найденными данными?